# My Function is not waiting other function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, spotify

getMyData() function have to wait refreshSpotifyToken() (its setting and updating the access token) but i couldnt do that...

I also have to execute refreshSpotifyToken() every 30 minutes to update my access token.

```
var spotifyWebApiNode = require('spotify-web-api-node')
spotifyApi = new spotifyWebApiNode();

var refresh = require('spotify-refresh')

var refreshToken = '<refresh token>';
var clientID = '<client id>';
var clientSecret = '<client secret>';

async function refreshSpotifyToken(){
    refresh(refreshToken, clientID, clientSecret, function (err, res, body) { 
        if (err) return
    
        spotifyApi.setAccessToken = body.access_token;
        console.log('Spotify Access Token Successfully Refreshed');
    })
}

setInterval(async () => {
    await refreshSpotifyToken();
}, 30*30*1000)


async function getMyData(){
    await refreshSpotifyToken();
    
    const data = await spotifyApi.getMe();
    let userId = data.body.id;

    getMyPlaylist(userId);
}

async function getMyPlaylist(userId){
. . .
```

Comment: refreshSpotifyToken is using callback, you have to convert to Promises first

Comment: `refreshSpotifyToken` does not wait for `refresh`